# How to create package-info.java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I want to create a `package-info.java` to add package-wise comments, but in current version of Android Studio (I am using 0.5.7 and I don't know about this possibility in older versions) I am facing these issues:

When I right click on package and select NEW, there is no option for creating a package info file. I tried to create a new class and name it `package-info.java` but the IDE doesn't like this name and does not allow me to create this file.

So I went ahead and created a class file named `PackageInfo.java` and wrote to it what you usually write in the `package-info.java`.

The problem is when I use the `Generate JavaDoc` from Tools menue, it does not care about this file and it contents does not show up.

So I wonder if you have any workaround or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best workaround is to right click on the package, New, File, and create a file called package-info.java. Once it's there the IDE will recognize it as a Java file and you'll get the syntax highlighting and such.

Comment: Well thats a nice workaround! it seems to work...why on earth I didnt try that myself lol

Comment: More info about `package-info.java` file: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/